# Unpacking the Diagonal Lemma

Tags: logic, computability

I am studying from Boolos' Computability & Logic (3rd edition). I need help unpacking what the Diagonal Lemma states, and understanding its proof. The Diagonal lemma is formalized on page 105 from these [notes](http://tedsider.org/teaching/510/notes.pdf), it appears as lemma 2.

Diagonal Lemma states:

> Let $T$ be a theory in which $\operatorname{diag}$ is representable. Then for any formula $B(y)$ (in the language of $T$, containing just the variable $y$ free), there is a sentence $G$ such that $\vdash_T G\leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$.

The terms utilized in this lemma are defined on the previous pages. I need help unpacking what this lemma states. What does $B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ mean? I know $\ulcorner G\urcorner$ is defined to be the Gödel number of a sentence $G$. I do not understand what $B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ means though.

Also, within the proof it states

> Since $A(x,y)$ represents $\operatorname{diag}$ in $T$, one can think of it as meaning, informally, that “$y$ is the (g.n. of the) diagonalization of (the formula whose g.n. is) $x$”.

Does that mean that there is diagonalization of a formula, and the diag (Gödel number of the diagonalization) is represented as $x$ & that the $y$ is the diag (Gödel number) of $x$?

That doesn't make any sense to me, since I don't understand how a Gödel number which is some sequence of numbers that represents a formula, could also have a Gödel number. Since the original Gödel number is just a string of numbers.

Please help me unpack what Lemma 2 states (especially what $B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ means) and what $A(x,y)$ means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't attempt to explain the exact wording of the proof in your link, but I will explain the proof using the same notation. I think you can go back to the link afterwards and make sense of it.

The Diagonal Lemma says: Let $T$ be a theory in which we can represent the process of diagonalization. Then every formula $B(y)$ in the language of $T$ "detects truth" for some sentence $G$. In other words,

$$T \vdash G \leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$$

So that $T$ proves $G$ is true if and only if $B$ holds for the Gödel number of $G$.

Proof: We first build a new formula $F$. This formula takes a value $x$, plugs $x$ into the $x$th formula, and then takes the Gödel number of that sentence and sticks it into $B$. In other words,

$$F = \exists y \Big(A(x,y) ~~ \& ~~ B(y)\Big)$$

As we have defined it, $F$ is a function of $x$. Let $n$ be its Gödel number. Now, we plug $n$ into $F$, to obtain a sentence $G = F(n)$. In essence, we obtain $G$ by giving the Gödel number of $F$ as input to itself.

We now claim that this $G$ is the sentence we have been searching for. Let $k$ be the Gödel number for $G$. We want to show that

$$T \vdash G \leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G \urcorner) (= B(k))$$

Now, $T \vdash G$ iff $T \vdash F(n)$. But $T \vdash F(n)$ iff $T$ proves that $B$ holds for the Gödel number of the sentence given when plugging $n$ into the $n$th function. However, recall that the Gödel number of the sentence given when plugging $n$ into the $n$th function is just $\ulcorner F(n) \urcorner = \ulcorner G \urcorner = k$. Thus, $T \vdash F(n)$ iff $T \vdash B(k)$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: You can get the Quine corners with `\ulcorner` and `\urcorner`.